# How can I do a point read without knowing the partition key using .Net SDK V3?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using AzureCosmos SDK3 and trying to fetch an item details from Cosmos db by using ReadItemAsync method. My container has got multiple Partition Key and while fetching data I do not want to specify Partition Key.

```
var item = container.ReadItemsAsync<T>(itemid, PartitionKey.None);
```

Specifying PartitionKey as None also not working.

Comment: If you don't want to specify the partition key when getting an item from a container, you'll need to structure your data model so that all the items you want to retrieve are stored in the same partition.

Comment: Yes that is an option but I cannot do that as this is a legacy Db and being used in many client app. So don't want to go for structure change. We are upgrading to Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos v3 from earlier SDK. I thought of setting up enablecrosspartition setting but that is also not working.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do a point read if you do not know the Partition Key Value of the document.

The document's identity is the `id` and the Partition Key Value, you can have multiple documents with the same `id` but in different Partition Keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetItemQueryIterator` it's required only query and it will fetch all the required data as per query.

e.g.

```
var query = container.GetItemQueryIterator<TestDoc>("SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id = 'foo'");
while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    var doc = await query.ReadNextAsync();
    foreach(var x in doc.Resource)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Retrieved document {x.Id}");
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct but note that this will incur additional cost as it will hit the query engine and result in a cross-partition query which will multiply the query RU cost but the number of physical partitions. If at all possible you should try and design your application to specify the partition key, especially in the scenario of a point read of a single item.

Comment: @mackie agree for single item I used it with Partition Key only